# Finding closure of a specific subset of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have the following definitions:
$$\begin{split}
    A_2 &= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ :\ x \in (-1,1),\  y^2 < \frac{3}{2}(1-x^2)\right\}, \\
    B_2 &= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ :\ x \in (-1,1),\  y^2 < \frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)\right\};
\end{split} $$
hence $A_2$ and $B_2$ are open sets of elliptical shape, with $B_2 \subseteq A_2$.

My aim is to find the closure of the set $C = A_2 \setminus B_2$. I can "see" that in fact $\overline C = \overline{A_2} \setminus B_2$, but I can't seem to prove this starting from the usual properties of closure, set difference, complements, etc. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: let $(x,y) \in \overline {A_2} \setminus B_2$. Then $\frac 1 2(1-x^{2}) \leq y^{2} \leq \frac 3 2(1-x^{2})$. Observe that one of the inequalities has to be strict. If the left inequality is strict consider $\{(x,(1-\frac 1 n)y)\}$ and if the right one is strict consider $\{(x,(1+\frac 1 n)y)\}$. Conclude that $(x,y)$ is the limit of  sequence from $C$. This gives one inclusion and the other inclusion is obvious since $B_2$ is open.